# Where are threads stored in memory relative to other process structures during execution on a windows x86 system

Tags: windows, multithreading, memory-management, process, stack

So a process is:

------DOS header/PE header

------executable code and statically linked libraries

------slack space?

------some dynamically linked libraries

------start of heap

------slack space

------top of stack

------bottom of stack

I am unsure of where the kernel mode stack and user mode stacks are relative to eachother in the virtual memory allocated for the process stack - also, when a new thread is spawned by a multithreaded process, where is the virtual memory allocated for it?

Thanks!

Comment: That diagram is not correct. Everything in user-mode is all mixed together. The heap may be in multiple chunks with a stack stuck in between, etc. (It looks like that diagram was inspired by the memory layout of processes in 16-bit Windows, but I doubt that's what you're asking about.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On x86 Windows, the kernel-mode modules are located in the (virtual) memory space from `0x80000000`, which is not accessible from a user mode process, and all the user-mode modules are located in the memory space before `0x80000000`.

When a new (user-mode) thread gets spawned, a new memory page is allocated for its stack in both the user-mode memory space (accessible from both user-mode and kernel-mode) and kernel-mode memory space (accessible only from the kernel mode). Note that there are some system threads that do not have a user mode context (thus no stack allocated in any of the user-mode processes). These threads purely run in the kernel and do not run under user-mode.

Comment: Yea I knew about the highest 2GB being for kernel mode...so it just spawns a new page for each thread, whether kernel or user, and the thread exists as a stack data structure in that page with some kind of thread header (and CPU state for thread switching)?

Comment: @Andrew Oh, the metadata for the threads (e.g. thread contexts, priority, etc.), with the exception of TEB (thread environment block), lie entirely in the kernel (`KTHREAD` and `ETHREAD` structures). They are linked as a linked list and are used by the scheduler.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped clear up a lot of my confusion in my mental model of runtime memory management

Comment: I don't get it, so the user mode stack is in the process's stack space or just some random place ?

Comment: @zinking Simply think of stack (both user and kernel modes) as a chunk of memory which the stack pointer (ESP register) points to. That chunk is allocated in the kernel space for kernel mode stack, and user space for user mode stack.